# Group data under conditions

Tags: r

I am working with R on cross-section data and having a problem when grouping the data under conditions. The problem can be seen clearly from a small part of my huge database as following. I would like to calculate the Average (Distance) under the conditions of same Province, District and Commune.

```
Province    District    Commune  Distance
101           15           3      15
101           15           3       5
101           15           3       7
101           15           9       1
101           15           9       7
102           18          19       3
102           18          19       10
103           16          22       5
103           16          22       6
```

The expected results would be the following (divided by each specific commune for each district and each province):

```
Province    District    Commune    Distance
101           15           3       average
101           15           9       average
102           18           19      average
103           16           22      average
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Province, District, Commune) %>% 
    summarise(Distance=mean(Distance))
```

Or

```
aggregate(Distance~., df1, mean)
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, list(Distance=mean(Distance)), .(Province, District, Commune)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the following:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Province, District, Commune), summarize, val = mean(Distance))
```